# When Migrating data from salesforce to SQL server using Talend tool getting Error

Tags: integration, talend

I want to migrate data from salesforce to SQL Server using Talend Tool. so I have created a job in talend tool and when run the job i got following error:

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/talend/salesforce/SforceConnection : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
Exception in thread "main"

and also In the Repository tree, when creating salesforce connection using " Create Salesforce Connection"-its not working..

Can any one help me what is the problem and how to resolve this issue...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "major.minor version 51.0" in the message corresponds to Java 7. (See e.g. [Java class file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) for the numbers.) So the problem is probably that you are trying to run code compiled for Java 7 using say a Java 6 runtime.

To confirm this, check the Talend documentation for its required Java version, and check the version of Java you have by entering `java -version`. Upgrade your Java version to fix.